# Howto distinguish between Uri result and other activities

Tags: android, uri, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a onActivityResult method in my Activity. I get the Bundle and distinguish between different actions by comparing a string value ("function")

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // if (requestCode == REQUEST_QUICKLIST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {

                String sFunction = extras.getString("function");
```

Now I would like to additionally handle the new Lollipop feature `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to show up an tree dialog, which the user choose an folder to save stuff. This action will also be handled by `onActivityResult`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
        DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
```

Howto distinguish between my notmal actions and the tree action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Request Code with `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode);`

And in `onActivityResult()`

before `if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)` check `requestCode` with it.

Like,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request you're responding to .. it differentiate your Activity and Tree action
    if (requestCode == <YOUR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE>) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // Do something with the result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More info about request and result with intent look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

> Howto distinguish between my notmal actions and the tree action ?

Use different request codes in your `startActivityForResult()` calls. Those will be delivered as the first parameter to `onActivityResult()`, and you can have logic in `onActivityResult()` to examine that request code and branch accordingly.